# Is there a resource that offers a detailed overview of the gradient flow?

Tags: deep-learning, reference-request, backpropagation, gradient-descent

Understanding the concept of "Gradient Flow" can be quite difficult as there is a lack of widely recognized and clearly defined resources that provide a comprehensive explanation. Although you can find insights from machine learning experts and references to papers that mention gradient flow, there isn't a single, definitive source that thoroughly covers the topic.

Could you please recommend a resource that offers a detailed overview of the gradient flow?

Comment: Please share the insights that you have seen. This provides context for others trying to help you out!

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind the context is surrounding this video with the rest of Andrew Ng's work. So please watch that to get a better background.
" In the beginning there is Time. Time moves, and creates dynamics on Space."

- [1.2.5 Gradient Descent by Andrew
  Ng](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFPLyDwVifc)
- [Gradient descent is in discrete time, gradient flow is in continuous
  time](http://awibisono.github.io/2016/06/13/gradient-flow-gradient-descent.html)

**Links**

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFPLyDwVifc
2. http://awibisono.github.io/2016/06/13/gradient-flow-gradient-descent.html
3. https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=gradient+descent+and+gradient+flow

First time answering on this site so please comment and I will fix what I can.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the Machine Learning Crash Course for understanding Gradient Descent. Yes, of course, this course is primarily aimed at an introduction to Tensorflow, but the initial lessons will help you in studying your question.
https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course

I would also recommend this incredibly cool article for study. This is the best I've come across on this subject, but it will take you some time to figure it out. After studying it (and a number of others), I finally managed to write my first vanilla neural network:
https://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/